# MongoDB taking lot of time to query large number of records

Tags: c#, mongodb

MongoDB is taking lot of time to return 800 records. it takes almost 30-35 seconds. whereas local db with 23,000+ records take 1 seconds. This gives me clue that the issue comes when db is remote.

Looking for help from the community in this area.

> _database points to IMongoDatabase and mongodb driver for c# is being used for this code.

```
var options = new FindOptions<SomeEntity>
            {
                Sort = Builders<SomeEntity>.Sort.Descending(x => x.Id),
                BatchSize = 1000
            };

            var someEntities = await _database
                .GetCollection<SomeEntity>("SomeEntity")
                .FindAsync(rule => true, options).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var list = new List<SomeEntity>();

            while (await someEntities.MoveNextAsync())
            {
                list.AddRange(someEntities.Current.ToList());
            }
```

Comment: What is the connection speed to the remote database? Downloading 800 large objects with a slow connection speed could be the problem

Comment: are you sure its the query or as MindSwipe suggests the transfer of the actual data

Comment: @MindSwipe it's very slow as server is located far off with low speed

Comment: @BugFinder I don't think it's query, as it works fast on local db with many times higher records in number. I am looking for some direction to analyze this. however  I am open to suggestions from the community to root cause this

Comment: Then you probably have your problem. If this really is the problem then no code you write can fix this, the only solution is to get a faster connection to the database. You can see if this is really the problem by downloading a sizeable file and measuring the time it takes. The only thing you could possibly do to reduce the time needed with your code is to reduce the size of the selected object, ergo select less data

Comment: Local DB is probably using SQL Server (mdf file) while MongoDb is a totally different database. So you are comparing the access time of two different types of database.  Why are you using MongoDb when you can simply just use SQL Server and remote connect to server?

Comment: @jdweng local and remote both are mongo

Comment: Databases the same size?  Same version?   The long time can either be the querying of the database or the amount of data transferred (or both).  I would first try running the query locally on the remote machine to see the time.   If it takes a long time than it is the remote database.  If takes a short time than it is the data transfer.  You may have network issues that is slowing down the query.